# Почему при установлении breakpoint'a в call stack отображается одна анонимная функция, хотя в скрипте их несколько?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, отладчик

Вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Call Stack показывает последовательность вызовов функций. [Отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome#a)

Точка останова была установлена на 15 строке. К 15 строке было вызвано 2 НЕанонимные функции - `f1`, `f2`.

P. S. Также непонятно почему две глобальные переменные - `global1` и `global2` не имеют значений? С чего вдруг `undefined`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> К 15 строке было вызвано 2 НЕанонимные функции

Эти функции уже были вызваны, отработали и вернулись. Смысл "call stack"-а - последовательность *вложенных* вызовов функций, приведшая к данной точке.

Поставьте breakpoint внутри `f1` или `f2` и увидите.

Comment: А для чего вообще тогда точка останова, если можно просто двигаться по коду с помощью тех же `Step over`, `Step into` и смотреть что происходит в данный момент (переменные, функции)? В чем конкретно польза? Потому что я думала, что все переменные и функции (в `Call stack` и `Scope`) показываются за весь отработанный код до поставленного breakpoint'a, оказывается нет...

Comment: @Eva Затем, что мы очень быстро задолбаемся ходить по коду построчно. Это в Вашем примере всего 15 строчек. Представьте, что их несколько десятков тысяч.

Comment: @Eva ... Не говоря уже об асинхронности.